# Cannot create ActiveX component in Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I am facing a problem in vb.net forms application. I'm loading the Internet Explorer using the following code.

```
Dim browser As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
browser.Visible = TRUE
```

When creating the application for first time, it works fine. Loads the Internet Explorer correctly. But for second time if run the application the following run time error is occurring.

> Cannot create ActiveX component at the CreateObject line.

I don't know what is wrong with the application and I searched and google lot but did not find the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Out-of-process COM servers are never not a problem.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab and keep an eye on the number of iexplore.exe instances.  It can easily get out of hand when you terminate your program while debugging so normal cleanup does not happen.  Do favor WebBrowser.

Comment: It also gives error when i'm not debugging. So what is the solution for this?

Comment: But giving error message is not the solution bro.

Comment: I found the solution from this link, http://suraj1693.blogspot.com/2017/08/solved-cannot-create-activex-component.html

Answer (score -1):

If you're using library Interop.Excel or Interop.Work,
It has caused too many processes (Excel.exe or Work.exe), you have to End Process that process.

[image]